# Reordering Images When Using "Library" In 2sxc

Tags: 2sxc

This is probably best answered by Daniel, but others may know the answer...

Is it possible to re-order the images when uploading files/ images using the "Library" content type.

Currently if a client comes back and wants to change the order, we have to remove all the images, and upload them in the specific order.

EDIT:

Just found there's a discussion here:
[Sort 2sxc adam files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517683/sort-2sxc-adam-files/37561024#37561024)

Have things progressed since? It would be great to drag drop the images into the order!

See below for screenshot:

[image: 2sxc Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Basically manual ordering is not in the scope at the moment. There are a few ways to implement this though, depending on your needs.

A common way is to have a weight-information giving an image a priority - this would be done as a metadata field. Your razor would then have to respect this when sorting it.